# Jar file for running apache spark examples

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to execute Spark example code at:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/cassandra_inputformat.py

It says I need to execute it with an example jar. I tried running it with the jar SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-examples-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar , but it results in an exception 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

I am running pre-built spark 1.2 for hadoop 2.4 and cassandra 2.1.2

Am I not using the correct jar file for executing the program?